# How to add the Background-color to the Schedule Date Selected

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, background-color

How to add the Background-color to the Selected Date in the Schedule Tag in the Primefaces ?

I have already used style but it going for the Schedule Background color. i want  to get the Background -color to my selected Date inside the Schedule .So if u guys have any ideas please share it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style class you are looking for is

```
ui-state-highlight
```

The [Primefaces documentation](http://primefaces.org/documentation.html) explains how to change the style for a particular component:

In your facelet:

```html
<p:schedule styleClass="custom">
...
</p:schedule>
```

And in your css:

```html
.custom .ui-state-highlight {
    background: yellow !important;
}
```

UPDATE 1:

Here is a complete working example:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"     
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .custom .ui-state-highlight {
                background: yellow !important;
            }
        </style>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <p:schedule styleClass="custom">
        </p:schedule>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 2:

Well, basically a primefaces schedule day is a table cell like this:

```html
<td class="fc-fri ui-widget-content fc-day19">
  <div>
    <div class="fc-day-number">18</div>
    <div class="fc-day-content">
      <div style="position:relative">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</td>
```

Notice that there is a special style class `fc-day19` for the table cell with content `18`.

The following jQuery command changes the background-color of this cell based on this special class:

```html
$(".fc-day19").css("backgroundColor","green");
```

This is not the complete solution of your problem but this is how it *could* work. You need to identify the table cell of your desired date and change its style accordingly (note that the css `background-color` needs to be camel-cased to `backgroundColor` if it is used in jQuery. Hope this helps.

Comment: http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?p=64420#p64420   Check out this Link Please...that is the code and that is the image i got ..I have tried the Code given by u also..because of that i was not able to display the date i have selected in the Schedule..

Comment: It works for me. Updated my anser with the complete working example.

Comment: Hey Matt Thanks for that..now i am able to change my date atleast with that...but i am not able to get this background to my Selected Date ..it is going to the default..Date only but not to my selected date..

Comment: I don't know if this is possible since there is no special css class for this (of course you could select the underlying table cell somehow). Alternatively add an event to your model on the server when the date is selected and highlight it this way.

Comment: you see i am getting my selected Date display in the Schedule through the attribute "initialDate" in the Schedule Tag so is there any possibility of adding like " .ui-state-highlight-initialDate{}"

Comment: So Matt ..any suggestions of highlighting the Date what i have selected..in the Schedule ?